# std::vector, member access operator and EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: c++, stdvector

Why can I execute an `operator&` from a (*iterator), but can not make copy of value (*iterator) ?

```
std::vector<int> v;   // yes, container is empty
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    auto it = v.begin();
    std::cout << &*(it) << std::endl;   // 0   <- why not EXC_BAD_ACCESS?
    auto value = *(it);                 // EXC_BAD_ACCESS
    auto address = &value;
}
```

Comment: For me after giving v some elements it all worked (in g++,clang,msvc)

Comment: You should not assume that bad code (in your case `*(it)`) always produces an error. Instead all it means is that the behaviour of your code is undefined. For such code questions like 'why' and 'why not' are meaningless.

Comment: @BotondHorváth I think the point is that `v` has no elements.

Comment: Undefined behaviour is undefined.

Comment: @john i assumed that in the real case it wasn't, he just forgot to put initialivation in the example. If `v` fas no elements `*it` kindof means `v[0]` which is UB (index out of range)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`v` is empty, hence `v.begin() == v.end()` and dereferencing `it` is undefined.

Comment: Could you please refer to documentation or other source to understand why `*(v.end())` is Undefined behaviour?

Comment: @SupporterMike [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/end): "This element acts as a placeholder; attempting to access it results in undefined behavior. "

Answer (score 1):

In theory, both have undefined behaviour and anything can happen in either case.

In practice, `&*(it)` does not access any memory; you don't need to read from a location in memory in order to determine what that location is.
(Somewhat similarly, you can figure out the address of a house without entering it, and the house doesn't even have to exist.)

Copying something, on the other hand, *does* require you to read what that thing is.

Comment: An accessible explanation why dereferencing such an iterator does not yet throw an exception. Together with the answer from @463035818-is-not-a-number fully answers the question.